# Ubuntu 15.10 error while install mysql-server

Tags: 15.10

i've been trying to install mysql-server but while installing i encounter this error what might be the solution to it ?`

```
 sudo aptitude install mysql-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.6{a} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  mysql-server 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,744 kB of archives. After unpacking 52.4 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Preconfiguring packages ...              
(Reading database ... 387903 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.6.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.6, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server
```

Comment: Do you have mariadb-server installed?

Comment: yes but i removed it before installing mysql

Comment: It would appear that parts of the mariadb server are still present.

Comment: removed all the components of mariadb ,, now it has be solved thanks ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install mysql-server/client on ubuntu 16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852562/cant-install-mysql-server-client-on-ubuntu-16)

Answer (score 1):

`Mariadb` [a fork of the `mySql`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) project registers currently as sql server version 10.  To allow the installation of `mySql` you will need to either remove all of the components of `Mariadb` or go through contortions to install the two database servers side-by-side.

[This article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/) describes how to run `Mariadb` alongside `mySql`, written for centOs, and not entirely easy to read along. Using this as a guide, you *might* be able to install both dBs.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.6, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.`

So, you can run the following commands to fix this problem:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
sudo apt-get -f install
```