# unmet dependency error on ubuntu 14.04 while installing

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql, dependencies

whenever I am trying to install `php5` or `my-sql` I am getting below error.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be   installed
>    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or    specify a solution).

What's the problem here.

Comment: What happens when you run: `apt-get -f install` as suggested in the error?

Comment: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/V7qVA6Ya) the result

Answer (score 1):

[Your log](http://pastebin.com/V7qVA6Ya) shows that [MariaDB 10.0 is present (the same error)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705568/ubuntu-15-10-error-while-install-mysql-server), and dpkg fails on version check (it thinks you perform downgrade). Try to remove MariaDB or make the following (I do not know, whether MariaDB would work after installation of mysql over it):

```
sudo -i rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
```