# package mariadb-common error - E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql, mariadb

I have `apt instal mariadb-server` several times (and of course each time apt remove). now, I cannot install it anymore. The error I am getting:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-common
 mariadb-server-core-10.0
 mariadb-client-core-10.0
 mariadb-client-10.0
```

This error even appears when I install other packages (they end successfully, but at the end I see the above errors, but `mariadb` anyway, does not install successfully).

I have used `purge`, `autoclean` and `autoremove` of `apt` and also have removed mysql conf files after unistalling it, but to no avail, I can't install mariadb-server successfully never again.

Now, what should I do?

**UPDATE**

Here is the error output:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-core-10.0 (10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-10.0 (10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: After the purging, did you look if there are still folders in `/usr/share/mysql*`?

Comment: Can you please add the full output of `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server` ?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: as commented by @Ziazis after removing files from dir /user/share/mysql it worked fine. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt purge mariadb* -y | sudo apt purge mysql* -y
sudo apt autoremove -y | sudo apt autoclean -y
sudo rm -R /usr/share/Mariad* | sudo rm -R /usr/share/Mysq*
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. A bunch of commands does not constitute a good answer. Please edit your answer and explain what these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Related question:
[Can't install mysql-server/client on ubuntu 16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852562/cant-install-mysql-server-client-on-ubuntu-16)

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/852565) by Bidyut worked for me. I had this part of your error:

```
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

But I did not have the error you had before it:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
```

I purged packages belonging to MySQL and MariaDB. Then, I deleted `/var/lib/mysql`:

`$ sudo rm -R /var/lib/mysql`

That line solved it for me. Then, when I tried to install either `mysql-server` or `mariadb-server`, it completed successfully without errors.

Sorry, I am not allowed to write this as a comment or connect a related question as a Guest.